# Objective C Dependency Management w/ Static Libs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dependencies, static-libraries

I'm looking for a solution to dependency management for a large Objective C (iOS) project. Right now we have multiple static libs built, which have to be pulled down from git by each developer, the code added as a submodule and compiled along with the project.  I've looked through a lot of posts, but haven't found exactly what I want.

Ideally, I'm looking for something similar to Maven 2 for Java. A tool that:

a) Manages dependencies of a project or static lib
b) Can handle multiple versions (proj A -> lib 1.0, proj B -> lib 1.1, etc)
c) Pulls down only the static lib endstates (.a) if possible.

I realize item c might not be possible as the .h files are needed to define the API, but wanted to put that out there in case there's some magic about static libs that I'm not aware of.

I've looked at [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) and [VendorKit](http://vendorkit.com/), but both are doing something similar to what we have now.

Answer (score 1):

(Author of CocoaPods here.)

I think I’m missing the part that makes CocoaPods not a suitable solution for your problem, could you elaborate?

In case you don’t want the dependency resolution etc of CocoaPods, you might be able to use just [the part which modifies/creates Xcode projects](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) to do just what you need.

Comment: sorry, somehow I missed your response until now. Part c was my main question.  I can build the project with CocoaPods so it pulls in all the .h and .m's (in order to build the libPods.a) but I'd like to not have to build that entire group of .m's all the time.  I'd rather just have the .a and the headers pulled in, link against those, and go.

Is it possible to pull the .a endstates and headers from a repo? If so, is there a good example out there? Thanks for creating the project BTW - very cool.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/98  I'll do some more investigation on that thread.  Thanks!